# Google Shopping API and Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, atom-feed, google-shopping

Can Zend Framework interface with Google Shopping and send data about our products?

From what I understand the interface is based on a modified Atom feed.

Zend currently provides a library for interfacing with Google Base, but as far as I can tell that service has been deprecated in favour of Google Shopping API.  Is there a replacement library for Google Shopping, or will I need to build my own (maybe on top of zend_feed_atom)?

I'm totally new to the Google APIs and would appreciate some guidance on where to start with them, but if Zend can do some of the gruntwork that would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Shopping API with your existing application by using the Content API for Shopping for PHP. Documentation and more details are on https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/developers-guide-php.